# How to connect pick points of a histogram by a curve in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram, curve-fitting

I am beginner in Matlab.
I have a histogram of a set of data I need to do 2 things.
1) I need the vertical axes to be normalized.
2) To curve a fit that passes through all the pick points of my Histogram bars.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll find that your questions will be better received if you let us know what you've tried. If you don't have code to post, have you rejected other solutions you've found (and if so, why?) or even tried to research ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it along these lines:

```
data = randn(1,1000); %// example data
num_bars = 15; %// specify number of bars

[n x] = hist(data,num_bars); %// use two-output version of hist to get values
n_normalized = n/numel(data)/(x(2)-x(1)); %// normalize to unit area
bar(x, n_normalized, 1); %// plot histogram (with unit-width bars)
hold on
plot(x, n_normalized, 'r'); %// plot line, in red (or change color)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For (1) try `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])`

For (2) try first drawing the histogram, then call `hold on`, then use the `plot` command.